# How can I use the contents of a PHP file in my script?

Tags: php, ftp, file-get-contents

I am developing the admin panel for my web application.  The front end of the site is on a server separate from the admin panel.  There is a form in the ACP where I want to be able to change the paths of my assets(img, js, css, etc) so all I have to do is change them in the form.  A helper function I created will apply the saved URL to any template assets.

Since the frontend and admin panel are on different servers, I have to use file_get_contents with the FTP protocol to read the assets config file of the frontend from the admin panel.  The file_get_contents function gets the content of the assets config file, but I want to be able to parse the actual PHP of the file and not just display the contents.

Example:

This is config/assets.php

```
<?php

$config = array(
    'img' => 'http://localhost/frontend/assets/img',
    'css' => 'http://localhost/frontend/assets/css',
    'js' => 'http://localhost/frontend/assets/js',
    'attachments' => 'http://localhost/frontend/attachments'
    );
```

How can I use the information from the file above in the file below....

This is my MVC(CodeIgniter) controller:

```
<?php

class Assets extends MY_Controller {

    function index(){

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        if($this->form_validation->run('assets') == FALSE){

            $this->template->overall_header("Asset Configuration");

            $this->load->config('assets');

            $config['acp'] = array(
                    'img_url' => $this->config->item('img_url'),
                    'css_url' => $this->config->item('css_url'),
                    'js_url' => $this->config->item('js_url'),
                    'attachment_url' => $this->config->item('attachment_url')
                    );

            $this->load->config('ftp_frontend');
            $content = file_get_contents('ftps://'.$this->config->item('username').':'.$this->config->item('password').'@'.$this->config->item('hostname').'/application/config/assets.php');

            /------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
            /-----  Pass variables to the admin cp form from the content of the front -----/
            /-----  end assets config file ------------------------------------------------/
            /------------------------------------------------------------------------------/

        }

    }

}
```

I hope I am explaining my problem well enough!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include` enabled, you can simply use `include` to include remote file. It is not advisable to do so for security reason, but for the sake of answer your question, you can do something like this.

```
include_once('ftps://'.$this->config->item('username') .
             ':'.$this->config->item('password') . '@' . 
             $this->config->item('hostname') . 
             '/application/config/assets.php');

var_dump($config);
```

Comment: Do you know where I could enable this?  Which server file?

Comment: @ShoeLace1291, check the following link. http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php